# Compile a string as a Compass file

Tags: ruby, sass, compass-sass

Is there a simple way to compile a string of text as a compass (sass) stylesheet?

Example input: `"section\n  background: darken(white, 10%)"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sass has:

```
-s, --stdin   Read input from standard input instead of a n input file
```

and

```
--compass  Make Compass imports available and load project configuration.
```

You could use popen with something like this:

```
output = IO.popen("sass -s --compass", "w+") do |pipe|
  pipe.puts "section\n background: darken(white, 10%)"
  pipe.close_write
  pipe.read
end
```

and output: `section {\n  background: #e6e6e6; }\n`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the class method [`Sass.compile`](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass.html#compile-class_method). To use `.sass` (indented) syntax you need to pass the `:syntax => :sass` option:

```
require 'sass'

Sass.compile "section\n background: darken(white, 10%)", syntax: :sass
#=> "section {\n  background: #e6e6e6; }\n"
```

**Note:** Compass itself doesn't provide an equivalent function so if you want all of Compass' goodies you'll need to `@import 'compass'` in your code.